# How to diff a commit with its parent

Tags: git, git-diff

Aside from writing an alias or script, is there a shorter command for getting the diff for a particular commit?

```
git diff 15dc8^..15dc8
```

If you only give the single commit id `git diff 15dc8`, it diffs that commit against HEAD.

Comment: The coolest thing about this would be that this would work with "git difftool", using the tools to show the diff.

Comment: For reference, the answer to this other question illustrates how you could set up a bash-powered alias to simplify the above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters-git-foo-aaa-bbb-ccc-foo-aaa-bar-bbb

Answer (score 700, accepted):

Use `git show $COMMIT`. It'll show you the log message for the commit, and the diff of that particular commit.

Comment: Too bad it can't use difftool :(

Comment: @orip you can always set GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF to a script that does the same thing as your difftool.

Comment: I prefer JakubNarebski's answer, as the commit expression given there will work in many contexts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/449128/992887

Comment: If there is not diff shown, there probably are no actual changes, like for a merge commit

Comment: This answer is technically off-topic -- not sure why it has so many votes.  The question was how to use `git diff` (and by implication `git difftool`), not `git show`.

Comment: @PTWithy: The question was, "Is there a shorter command for getting the diff for a particular commit?", which this question answers.

Comment: What is "$COMMIT"? Is it literally "$COMMIT"? Or is it an SHA-1 hash value?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: It's a commit hash, or the name of a commit (such as `HEAD`, `HEAD^`, `HEAD~3`, `some-branch-name`, etc.).

Comment: It does not answerd the question as it use alias, but it may be helpfull to others :
`[Alias]
     diff-commit="!f() (git log HEAD^${1}^! ; git difftool -d HEAD^${1}^! & ) ; f"`
Use it like `git diff-commit 2` to show diff with difftool between HEAD^2 and HEAD^3

Comment: why does "$COMMIT" work? what is "$COMMIT"

Comment: @simplename: Here, it is just a placeholder for whatever your commit hash is.

Comment: but that actually works. I literally put in `git show $COMMIT` and it shows me the changeset

Answer (score 505):

Use:

```
git diff 15dc8^!
```

as described in the following fragment of [git-rev-parse(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) man page (or in modern Git [gitrevisions(7)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) man page):

> Two other shorthands for naming a set that is formed by a commit and its
> parent commits exist. The r1^@ notation means all  parents of r1.  r1^!
> includes commit r1 but excludes all of its parents.

This means that you can use `15dc8^!` as a shorthand for `15dc8^..15dc8` anywhere in Git where revisions are needed.  For the *diff* command, the `git diff 15dc8^..15dc8` is understood as `git diff 15dc8^ 15dc8`, which means the difference between parent of commit (`15dc8^`) and commit (`15dc8`).

<sup>**Note**: the description in `git-rev-parse(1)` man page talks about revision ***ranges***, where it needs to work also for merge commits, with more than one parent. Then `r1^!` is "`r1 --not r1^@`" i.e. "`r1 ^r1^1 ^r1^2 ...`"</sup>

---

Also, you can use `git show COMMIT` to get the commit description and diff for a commit. If you want only the diff, you can use `git diff-tree -p COMMIT`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's much neater.  However, the last sentence of the git-rev-parse extract is rather confusing - seems like it means 'range from this commit's parent to this commit'.

Comment: @RichVel: it is a bit confusing because it tries to describe also the situation where commit has more than one parent (is a merge commit). r1^! works as expected also then.

Comment: @JakubNarębski: good point, maybe you could edit your answer to summarise your understanding of the single-parent and multi-parent cases - separate statements on each might be easier to understand.

Comment: @JakubNarębski: yes, much better!  I now use this shortcut all the time - thanks.

Comment: No need to specify the commit: `git difftool HEAD@{1}^!` works as well.

Comment: @jmiserez: `HEAD@{1}` specifies a commit. I'll explain that r1 can be any commit-ish.

Comment: The `^!` parent shorthand notation works properly with difftool for normal commits but the diff is reversed for merge commits. Why so?

Answer (score 60):

If you know how far back, you can try something like:

```
# Current branch vs. parent
git diff HEAD^ HEAD

# Current branch, diff between commits 2 and 3 times back
git diff HEAD~3 HEAD~2
```

Prior commits work something like this:

```
# Parent of HEAD
git show HEAD^1

# Grandparent
git show HEAD^2
```

There are a lot of ways you can specify commits:

```
# Great grandparent
git show HEAD~3
```

See [this page for details](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html).

Comment: HEAD^2 is not the grandparent, if HEAD^1 is daddy, then HEAD^2 is mommy. Use HEAD~2 for daddy's daddy.

Answer (score 12):

As [mipadi points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436362/how-to-diff-a-commit-with-its-parent/436368#436368), you can use `git show $COMMIT`, but this also shows some headers and the commit message. If you want a straight diff, use `git show --pretty=format:%b $COMMIT`.

This is, obviously not a very short hand, so I'm keeping this alias in my .gitconfig

```
    [alias]
      sd = show --pretty=format:%b
```

This enables me to use `git sd $COMMIT`to *show diff*.

Comment: This alias can include --color which makes it easier to read: sd = show --color --pretty=format:%b

Comment: @RichVel Indeed! Very good point. If you have colors enabled by default in git, you won't need this switch, though. That's what I normally do.

Answer (score 6):

Many of the mentioned examples (e.g. `git diff 15dc8^!`, or `git diff 15dc8^..15dc8`) don't work if you are using [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) and have `extendedglob` option set. You can fix it by one of the following three ways:

1. `unsetopt extendedglob` (and/or remove it from .zshrc)
2. `setopt NO_NOMATCH` (and/or set it in .zshrc)
3. escape the caret and bang every time with a backslash, e.g., `git diff 15dc8\^\!`

Comment: 4. _single_-quote the refs, e.g., `git diff '15dc8^!'`

Answer (score 4):

[Paul's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436362/how-to-diff-a-commit-with-its-parent/436696#436696) did what I was hoping it would.

```
$ git diff HEAD^1
```

Also, it's useful to add aliases like [hobs mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436362/how-to-diff-a-commit-with-its-parent/10408756#10408756). If you put the following in the [alias] section of your *~/.gitconfig* file then you can use the shorthand to view diff between head and previous.

```
[alias]
    diff-last = diff HEAD^1
```

Then running **$ git diff-last** will get you your result. Note that this will also *include* any changes you've not yet committed as well as the diff between commits. If you want to *ignore* changes you've not yet committed, then you can use diff to compare the HEAD with its parent directly:

```
$ git diff HEAD^1 HEAD
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git diff 15dc8 15dce~1
```

~1 means 'parent', ~2 'grandparent, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This uses aliases, so it doesn't answer your question exactly, but I find these useful for doing what you intend...

```
alias gitdiff-1="git log --reverse|grep commit|cut -d ' ' -f2|tail -n 2|head -n 2|xargs echo|sed -e 's/\s/../'|xargs -n 1 git diff"
alias gitdiff-2="git log --reverse|grep commit|cut -d ' ' -f2|tail -n 3|head -n 2|xargs echo|sed -e 's/\s/../'|xargs -n 1 git diff"
alias gitdiff-3="git log --reverse|grep commit|cut -d ' ' -f2|tail -n 4|head -n 2|xargs echo|sed -e 's/\s/../'|xargs -n 1 git diff"

alias gitlog-1="git log --reverse|grep commit|cut -d ' ' -f2|tail -n 2|head -n 2|xargs echo|sed -e 's/\s/../'|xargs -n 1 git log --summary"
alias gitlog-2="git log --reverse|grep commit|cut -d ' ' -f2|tail -n 3|head -n 2|xargs echo|sed -e 's/\s/../'|xargs -n 1 git log --summary"
alias gitlog-3="git log --reverse|grep commit|cut -d ' ' -f2|tail -n 4|head -n 2|xargs echo|sed -e 's/\s/../'|xargs -n 1 git log --summary"
```