# Git stash is changing files contents

Tags: git, git-stash

Very time I hit git stash it is changing my files to their state in the previous commit. Why is this happing and how did stop this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stash changes while keeping the changes in the working directory in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843384/stash-changes-while-keeping-the-changes-in-the-working-directory-in-git)

Comment: no. changing my branch files to local masters contents

Comment: You'll have to provide more information then. `git stash` should remove all uncommitted changes from your working directory and restore to the previous commit. The changes are stored in your stash (you can get them back via `git stash pop` or `git stash apply`). However, your original question says nothing about master, just "previous commit", which is what `stash` is supposed to do.

Comment: What exactly is it that you expect/want it to do?

Comment: its resolved. My local master was throwing conflicts (I think I made changes in my local master manually). I created a new local master so it's fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Ev]ery time I hit git stash it is changing my files to their state in the previous commit.

That's what it's *supposed* to do.  What `git stash` does is commit your work (into two special temporary commits called a "stash"; these commits are not on *any* branch, making it easy to switch to another branch and recover them), then do a `git reset --hard`.  The `git reset --hard` resets your index and work-tree to match the current commit.

If you don't want that, don't use `git stash`.

Note that you *can* have `git stash` check out the committed index content after / instead-of doing a hard-reset.  I believe this option is intended to allow pre-commit hooks to run code-checking operations on the files that would be committed by `git commit`.  The option for this is `-k` (as in `git stash -k`).  There are a number of minor flaws with this strategy; see [How do I properly git stash/pop in pre-commit hooks to get a clean working tree for tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20479794/1256452)

Comment: My local master was throwing conflicts (I think I made changes in my local master manually). I created a new local master so it's fine now