# How can i stash without cleaning the working area?

Tags: git

I want to save the state of my working area but not as a commit.  Should I create a new branch, or is there a way to make a stash without cleaning the working area?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `git stash` makes commits, so in a sense, you're asking how to commit without committing. The only (or at least main) thing special about stash commits is that they're not on any branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because my program was doing unexpected things, i fix it by doing some change but i wasn't completely sure why that change fixed the problem, and a wanted to analyze it later on and continue working without the issue.

Comment: `git stash store "$(git stash create)"` should do it. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/53329520/658497

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's some way to ask stash to save and not remove changes from working tree... but this would work

```
git stash save "I'm saving"
git stash apply # apply stash, but don't remove it from list of stashes
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a commit, and then do a soft reset to back out the state of that commit into the stage and working directory:

```
git commit -m 'commit for saving'
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

The commit you made first would still be available in the reflog, if you wanted to apply it.  I actually prefer the answer given by @eftshift0, but this is an option if you wanted an actual commit outside of the stash stack.

Answer (score 1):

From [@Noam Manos' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53110729/how-can-i-stash-without-cleaning-the-working-area/64526467#comment100170061_53110729), use `git stash store "$(git stash create)"`. The advantage of this command is that the worktree is not touched (which could affect certain text editors/IDE's).

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/53329520/10462623

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
$ git stash
$ git pull - if you want to pull from the master/develop branch
$ git stash pop - To bring your changes back. You might need to resolve conflicts if there are any.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a branch and save your changes there, But as a commit

I assume you are in `master`branch.
First make a commit.

`git commit -m "your commit message"`

`git checkout -b NEWBRANCH`

Now you neet to come back to the master branch

`git checkout master`

convert your commit again to changes (unstage)

`git reset --soft HEAD^`