# git alias with optional parameter

Tags: git, parameters, alias

I want to ensure that my latest commit has the current date before I push. Since I always rebase to master before a merge + push, I made this alias:

```
[alias]
    sync = !git commit --amend --date=today && git rebase master
```

Problem is, it keeps launching my text editor asking for a new commit message. Is there a way to have an optional parameter, so that I can choose to use either:

```
git sync 'my commit message'
```

or

```
git sync
```

where the latter will simply use the existing commit message, whatever it happens to be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3321492/923794

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To apply the extra parameters to anything except the end of your alias’ “command line”, you will need to put your shell commands in a script. You can do it with an external script (like [jdelStrother’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621874/git-alias-with-optional-parameter/6621952#6621952)), or you can do it with an “inline” shell script.

You can use `-m` to feed `git commit` your new message or use the `-C HEAD`/`--reuse-message=HEAD` option to have it use the existing message and author (it would also reuse the author timestamp, but you are resetting that with `--date=…`). Using any of these options will prevent Git from opening an editor for your commit message.

Here it is as an “inline” shell script:

```
git config --global alias.sync '!sh -c '\''git commit --amend --date=today ${1+-m} "${1---reuse-message=HEAD}" && git rebase master'\'' -'
```

The core of this small script is the pair of conditional parameter expansions:

```
${1+-m} "${1---reuse-message=HEAD}"
```

When you call it with an extra parameter (i.e. your replacement log message), these expand to two shell words: `-m "<your new log message>"`. When you do not supply the extra parameter, they expand to just a single word: `"--reuse-message=HEAD"`.

The trailing dash is also important; it could be any shell word, the point is that something must be there because the shell will use it to initialize its `$0` parameter (which usually has a default value, so it is useless for the conditional expansion itself).

---

If I misunderstood and you actually want to see the editor when you do not supply the extra parameter, then use the single expansion `${1+-m "$1"}` instead of the pair of expansions.

Comment: --reuse-message=HEAD is just what I was looking for, however the script isn't working how I expected. The commit command seems to use the existing message regardless of whether I supply a parameter, and the rebase command always comes back with an error: When no parameter is supplied I get 'fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream master' When a parameter is supplied I get 'Usage: git rebase ...'

Comment: @ceramica It works for me (both giving a new message and reusing the old message, as well as the subsequent rebase), but I have to use something besides `--date=today`, since that is not valid. I used `--date="$(date "+%s %z")"` instead — the exact command I used to create the alias (that is working for me) is `git config --global alias.sync '!sh -c '\''git commit --amend --date="$(date "+%s %z")" ${1+-m} "${1---reuse-message=HEAD}" && git rebase master'\'' -'`.

Comment: I finally got it to work but I had to manually change the alias in my .gitconfig to: `"!sh -c 'git commit --amend --date=today ${1+-m} \"${1---reuse-message=HEAD}\" ; git rebase master' -"` I don't know why it needs the extra quotation marks, but the need for `;` to separate the commands suggests the first one is failing. Yet, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 6):

When your aliases start getting more complex, it's probably easiest just to create a separate script for them.  If you add a file 'git-sync' to your path, it will be automatically called when you do 'git sync'.

So, if you created that file with something along the lines of -

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  git commit --amend --date=today
else
  git commit --amend --date=today -m "$1"
fi
git rebase master
```

- that would probably work.  It's typed off the top of my head though, so caveat lector.

Comment: The idea is sound, but this script does not do the conditional execution (`&&`) like the OP’s original code.