# Using and checking for optional parameters in a git alias function

Tags: macos, git, bash

I'm trying to do some crazy *git-fu* with aliases. Specifically, I want a git alias to read the incoming parameters based on whether they're empty, handle the command differently; kind of like overloading a function. I've gotten some good ideas for creating functions from other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621874/git-alias-with-optional-parameter) but dealing with the parameters in a smart way is still eluding me.

What I ended up doing is creating 3 functions for varying levels of specificity and calling them in a chain with default values. Here's a piece I have in my git config.

```
# get the current local branch
current = symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD


# Calls sync-branch-with-origin-master using the current branch for the first property and origin as the remote name.
# ex. `git sync master` will checkout master from origin, pull the latest, checkout your current branch and rebase it with master.
sync = "!f() { currentBranch=$(git current); git sync-branch-with-master $currentBranch $1; }; f"

# get latest version of branch 2 from origin and rebase branch 1 onto it.
sync-branch-with-master = "!f() { git sync-branch-with-origin-master $1 origin $2; }; f"

# get latest version of branch $3 from origin $2 and rebase branch $1 onto it.
sync-branch-with-origin-master = "!f() { git checkout $3; git pull $2 $3; git checkout $1; git rebase $3; }; f"
```

This works great! But what I'd really like is something that checks to see if $3 or $2 exist and handle those cases differently.

By the way, I'm using bash on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* write an entire script inside the shell function (`f()`, in each alias).  That quickly becomes quite unreadable/unmaintainable though.  For complex things I create a shell script and invoke that from the alias.

```
#! /bin/sh
# git-foo.sh
... body of script goes here ...
```

and then:

```
git config alias.foo '!git-foo.sh'
```

or whatever.

In this particular case, though, I suspect what you have is overkill :-)  You may just want to use `git pull --rebase` or `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`.  (Not that these are quite the same as what you have, so maybe not; but remember that `git pull` is basically the same as `get fetch` followed by `git merge`.)