# Get the path where git alias was run from

Tags: git, shell, git-alias

When an external command is run via Git alias, it is run from the rood directory of the repository (where the .git/ is usually located). It can be checked with:

```
$ cd /some/path/inside/repo
$ echo $(git -c alias.root='!pwd' root)
```

Now, **is there a way to get the exact path where the alias was run from?`**

---

In case of XY problem, here's what I'm doing: I want an alias that launches shell function which, in its turn, runs several Git commands, like ls-files. It should work only in the path where it was called, so it should know it.

It works well if I just run the function, because it doesn't change paths and runs exactly where it was called. But I want a little more native behaviour. What I have now is

```
git-add-specificname -opt -opt2 --long-option -- path1 path2
```

What I want is

```
git add-specificname -opt -opt2 --long-option -- path1 path2
```

Aliasing parameters in Git is not allowed, so no chance for `git add specificname...`

Comment: Translated this for [StackOverflow in Russian](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/438955/181472)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add `cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}` in your alias.

([Git 1.7.6+](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.6.txt#L29-L31):

> Processes spawned by "`[alias] <name> = !process`" in the configuration
>      can inspect `GIT_PREFIX` environment variable to learn where in the
>      working tree the original command was invoked.

[`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6f9504c48ea59951a2aa3ee17e7c7fc36285e225/Documentation/config.txt#L762-L763):

> '`GIT_PREFIX`' is set as returned by running '`git rev-parse --show-prefix`' from the original current directory.

)

If `GIT_PREFIX` is not defined (because you are executing the alias from the root folder of the repo), it will be replaced by '`.`'.

You can see that variable used in [`t/t1020-subdirectory.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/t/t1020-subdirectory.sh)

```sh
test_expect_success 'GIT_PREFIX for !alias' '
    printf "dir/" >expect &&
    (
        git config alias.test-alias-directory "!sh -c \"printf \$GIT_PREFIX\"" &&
        cd dir &&
        git test-alias-directory >../actual
    ) &&
    test_cmp expect actual
'
```

Comment: I'd been expecting a brilliant answer from you exactly. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin I just saw a similar answer (for a slightly different question): http://stackoverflow.com/a/21929373/6309

Comment: One more detail: what does the `:-.` syntax do?

Comment: @NickVolynkin That what I meant with "If GIT_PREFIX is not defined (because you are executing the alias from the root folder of the repo), it will be replaced by '.'.". When you execute an alias from the root folder, GIT_PREFIX is *not* defined. Hence the need to use '.' (current folder)

Comment: Oh, a substitution. Can't get used to shell's fancy syntax. ))