# Git checkout by commit order

Tags: git, commit, git-checkout

When I use Git checkout master~X, I will get the Xth merged commit, what I really 
want is the Xth real commit (not merged commits only).

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
git checkout $(git log --no-merges --skip=2 -1 --format='%H')
```

Change `--skip=2` to the number of non-merge commits you want to skip over. If you want the first non-merge commit, use `--skip=0`; the second non-merge commit, use `--skip=1`; the third, use `--skip=2`; etc.

---

You could set up an alias (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322412/649852) as a guide):

```
git config alias.co-non-merge '!git_co_non_merge() { git checkout `git log --no-merges --skip=$(($1 - 1)) -1 --format="%H"` ; } ; git_co_non_merge'
```

Add `--global` to make it a global configuration change. Then you could just use `git co-non-merge X`.

Comment: "merge commits" are "commits" too though, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

You could get a list of commits that are no merge commits using

```
git log --no-merges
```

In that list, simply take the X-th result to do the `checkout`.

For your use case, the [`--online`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-log.html) flag could additionally be used since the short display should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Merge commits can be replaced with rebase. Check this [article](http://www.viget.com/extend/only-you-can-prevent-git-merge-commits/) out. However it only has effect on future branches.