# git diff two sequential commits shortcut?

Tags: git

I'd like to define a shortcut "git diffn" with this behavior:

```
git diffn := git diff HEAD HEAD~1
git diffn 1 := git diff HEAD~1 HEAD~2
git diffn 2 := git diff HEAD~2 HEAD~3
...
```

First one is no problem, but I don't know to to make the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out myself. I've added to ~/.gitconfig this monstrosity:

```
[alias]
dn = "!sh -c 'if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then git diff HEAD~1 HEAD ; else git diff HEAD~`expr $1 + 1` HEAD~$1 ; fi' -"
```

After this,

```
git dn
```

works, as well as

```
git dn 1
git dn 2 
...
```

Comment: BTW: your `HEAD`s are swapped, should be: `git diff HEAD~1 HEAD` etc. I only noticed because I made the same mistake myself :)

Answer (score 8):

What about:

`git show` - shows the last commit

`git show HEAD~1` - shows the last but one commit

`git show <COMMIT SHA>` - shows you any commit

`git whatchanged` - shows you which files changed against the git log

Comment: Thanks for these commands. I haven't used them before, but some are useful. But that doesn't answer my question, which was about making a simple shortcut.

Comment: No, this is exactly what you want. To make an alias, put `alias gitdiffn='git show HEAD~$1'` in your .bashrc, but I think you figured out how to make it a git command alias

Comment: while git show HEAD~2 gives me the info that I want, it's not equivalent to what git diff HEAD~2 HEAD~1 does, since I've bound git diff to a script that calls meld when $DISPLAY is available and otherwise a plain diff.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood what your command did. You are right!

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly (to me), you can combine `~n` and `^` syntax, so this is how I was doing it:

`a=1; git diff HEAD^~$a HEAD~$a`

But there's a simpler way:

`a=1; git log -p -1 HEAD~$a;`

I find the extra commit info helpfully orienting, but you can customize that away. Note: the manpage notes some minor differences between this and diff's format, which might matter for  non-human consumption.

```
[alias]
diffn = "!sh -c 'git log -p -1 HEAD~$1' -"
```

Doesn't work with omitted arg, so I guess an `if` is needed for that.

BTW: found similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters-git-foo-aaa-bbb-ccc-foo-aaa-bar-bbb)