# git alias with bash conditional logic comparing strings - syntax issues

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

I'm working on a git alias and have run into syntax issues at its current (incomplete) state:

```
[alias]
gup2 = !git checkout $1 && BEFORE=$(git stash list) && git stash save gup-temporary-stash && git fetch && git rebase -p origin/$1 && if [ "$BEFORE" != "$(git stash list)" ]; then git stash pop; fi
```

The problem seems to start when the double quotes are introduced. I've tried many combinations of single quotes and double quotes with escape sequences, but I can't seem to find the right combination.

What is the syntactically correct way to form the above alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After
[a year](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/commits/master/.gitconfig)
of using a Git alias, I decided that they are not worth the trouble. In my mind, the only benefit of using an alias is so you can put

```
git foo
```

instead of

```
git-foo.sh
```

and in fact if your script is named as my example here, you can even call it as

```
git foo.sh
```

or if you name the script `git-foo` then you can even call it as

```
git foo
```

completely eliminating the benefit of git alias in my opinion. Git syntax for scripting is crap compared to just writing an external script, which
[I have done](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/5a7a79f/scripts/git-ac.sh).

Comment: I like `git s` for git status,  I've probably saved about 100 hours of time with that one, but otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: I generally agree, but if command is really small, having it fit into your config (where you may share config to multiple machines) can be useful.  I like the solution outlined here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3322412/652904 and I use it to launch external graphical diff tools to diff a single commit `meld1    = "!f() { git difftool -y -t meld    $1^ $1; }; f"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try either the character code of the character you want, or the hex name of the character you want. Here is a link to these things:

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

At the core of what you are doing, you are just writing a bash script in your environment. So whatever lets you write quotes outside of git's bash interface should be able to work here.