# Git alias log changing after date

Tags: git

I have an alias I want to use with code-maat and don't know how to do so where I can add the after when I run the alias. is this possible? For example, here is what I want to alias:

```
alias gmaat = 'git log --pretty=format:"[%h] %an %ad %s" --date=short --numstat --after=YYYY-MM-DD'
```

So what I need to do is have it when I run the gmaat alias, I either would be prompted to add the --after date or I would run

```
gmaat YYYY-MM-DD // filling in the date
```

If this is possible I appreciate in advance help that can be given.

**EDIT**

I tried the first answer below by adding this:

```
alias gmaat='!f() { git log --pretty=format:"[%h] %an %ad %s" --date=short --numstat --after=$1 }; f'
```

When I run this and add the date after the alias I get this error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '2014-11-01': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: I fjust fixed and tested the first part of the answer: the git alias works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [positional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322412/6309):

```
git config alias.gmaat '!f() { git log --pretty=format:"[%h] %an %ad %s" --date=short --numstat --after=$1; }; f'
```

Note the '`;`' inside the `{ xxx; }`

That way, you can pass `YYYY-MM-DD` as a parameter

```
git gmaat YYYY-MM-DD // filling in the date
```

Without using `git config alias`, you would then need [to define in your `~/.bashrc_profile` a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/6309):

```
gmaatf() { git log --pretty=format:"[%h] %an %ad %s" --date=short --numstat --after=$1 }
```

Then:

```
 alias gmaat=gmaatf
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Using the function worked perfectly.