# is there any way to make github desktop pull and push changes automaticcally

Tags: git, github, transfer, collaboration, github-desktop

### Automatic Push/Pull in Github Desktop

When working on Code in Visual Studio Git hub Desktop is my absolute favorite tool to use. It makes collaboration between me and my fellow programmers or even between my own laptops seamless, or almost anyway; It is really helpful being able to see the changes but it has one major problem, you have to click a button or two just to get or send the latest changes, **I am wondering if there is any way I can make it so that if I make a change it automatically pushes to the repository and vise versa.**

*For reference I have the latest version of git hub desktop as of 1019-02-19 or v 1.6.1*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would not be a feature directly available in GitHub Desktop.

You might consider a hook, for at least the push automation side, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28042939/6309).
Some editors, [like VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40282#issuecomment-352027501), can automatically and periodically fetch refs from your remotes. But if GitHub Desktop has no such capability, you would need to [setup some cron task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30263482/6309).

Comment: thank you for replying i will look into the hook and cron i understand that git hub desktop does not automatically include that but i thought it was worth asking about.