# Git alias with multiple commands and arguments

Tags: git

I am trying to create a global git alias to delete a local and a remote copy of a branch in one command. I would like the alias to take the following input:

```
$ git purge myBranch
```

And generate the following commands:

```
$ git branch -d myBranch
$ git push origin --delete myBranch
```

Among many other attempts, I've tried this:

```
$ git config alias.purge '!sh "git branch -d $1; git push origin --delete $1"'
```

But I get this error:

```
sh: 0: Can't open git branch -d myBranch; git push origin --delete myBranch
fatal: While expanding alias 'purge': 'sh "git branch -d $1; git push origin --delete $1"': No such file or directory
```

How can I create a global git alias that accepts an argument and forwards it to two separate git commands in this fashion?

**Update:**

Per @Chris' suggestion I've tried out the following:

```
git config --global alias.purge '!git branch -d $1 && git push origin --delete $1'
```

Here is the result:

```
$ git purge test
warning: deleting branch 'test' that has been merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/test', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch test (was 1316434).
error: dst ref refs/heads/test receives from more than one src.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:testrepo/repo.git'
```

I've confirmed that this works properly if I run the commands directly:

```
$ git branch -d test && git push origin --delete test
warning: deleting branch 'test' that has been merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/test', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch test (was b610eca).
To git@github.com:testrepo/repo.git
 - [deleted]         test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

My original answer will probably work in most cases, but it looks like the repetition of positional argument `$1` is generating a strange doubling effect.

For example:

```sh
git config --global alias.foo '!echo $1 && echo $1'
git foo bar
# bar
# bar bar
```

In this case it seems that the old [shell function technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322412/354577) works better:

```
git config alias.purge '!f() { git branch -d $1 && git push origin --delete $1; }; f'
```

This technique used to be very common, but [became unnecessary for most use cases sometime before 1.8.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters#comment26765758_3321492).

**Original answer:**

I have a similar alias in my `~/.gitconfig` file. Mine doesn't invoke `sh`, and it uses `&&` instead of `;` to ensure that the second command only runs if the first one succeeds.

Something like this should work for you:

```
[alias]
        purge = "git branch -d $1 && git push origin --delete $1"
```

Using `git config`:

```
git config alias.purge '!git branch -d $1 && git push origin --delete $1'
```

Comment: Here is the error I get when I use the latter config option: "Expansion of alias 'purge' failed; '!git branch -d $1 && git push origin --delete $1' is not a git command". I'm particularly interested in the config command since I need to automate the process of creating the alias.

Comment: @Jake, what if you remove the inner quotes, i.e. `git config alias.purge '!git branch -d $1 && git push origin --delete $1'`?

Comment: This is closer - updated my question. I will play around with this some more as soon as I have a chance, you've definitely helped get me in the right direction.

Comment: @Jake, I did some more testing and found a strange doubling effect when using the same positional argument (`$1`) in both commands. See if this works: `git config alias.purge '!f() { git branch -d $1 && git push origin --delete $1; }; f'`. It seems to do the trick for me. If it works for you I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Chris answer works well for me. I created this:

'!f() { git branch $1 && git checkout $1; }; f'
and it works like a charm