# Git alias to add prefix to name of new branch

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

Is there a way to write an alias that adds current date to name of new branch?

For example:

```
git branch-today new_branch_name
```

should create new branch with `22_09_2015_new_branch_name` name.

Comment: Wherever possible, please use YYYY-MM-DD ([ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm)).  The date format you have chosen (DD_MM_YYYY) is ambiguous.

Comment: @JaredBeck Strictly speaking, YYYY-MM-DD is just as ambiguous as DD_MM_YYYY. 1999-01-02 could be the second day of January, or the first day of February. It's not the format or the order of the components that makes it unambiguious - it's the agreed-upon interpretation of the format that makes it unambiguous. Thus, as long as all users of DD_MM_YYYY agree upon a "standard" interpretation, that format is just as valid as your ISO proposal. That said, I do tend to prefer ISO 8601-like formats for sortability...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a git alias and add it to your `.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
        branch-today = "!bt() { git branch $(date +%d-%m-%Y)_$1;}; bt"

git branch-today foo
```

Git branch output:

```
  22-09-2015_foo
* master
```

Comment: Can you explain the `!bt()`? I'm guessing the `!` starts a subshell and that `bt()` defines a bash function.

Comment: explained best here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters