# Git checkout feature/ shortcode

Tags: git

I am trying to add a function to my global gitconfig.

for example I made the following shortcuts.

```
com = checkout master
cod = checkout develop
```

Now I am trying to make a short command to make checking out features & release faster.

Want I basically want to create is the following

```
cof = checkout feature/
```

So i can run the following command

```
git cof feature-name
```

But because there shouldn't be a space in between the / and the name it's not working. Otherwise if I put no space in between it won't work either (which is logical)

```
git coffeature-name
```

Is there anyway I can fix this in a similar way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the alias you are looking for is something like the following:

```
cof = "!f() { FEATURE=$1; shift; git checkout $@ feature/$FEATURE; }; f"
```

This gives you all of the functionality of `git checkout` with a shorthand for feature branches. This allows you to use the `-b`, `-B`, or `--orphan` flags for creating a new branch; `--` for specifying a path; etc.

#### Nondescript Shorthand Explanation

- `!`: Tells git the alias is an alias for the shell.
- `f()`: define a function within the brackets
- `f`: after the braces executes the function

#### Function Logic

- `FEATURE=$1; shift;`: The function takes the first argument, assigns it to a variable, then removes it from the list of arguments.
- `git checkout $@ feature/$FEATURE`: Pass all the arguments you passed (except the first one which is the feature name) to `git checkout` with an argument having `feature/` prefixed to the feature name.

Comment: Nice! This helped. Thanx!

Comment: If I want to make this for release and hotfix. I just use the f? Or can i change to to r & h?  Because down here I read something about copy pasting with the bt.

Comment: @DannyvanHolten `f` is just the name of the function that is declared inline and called in the alias.  It can be anything you want, something more meaningful perhaps.  But the definition only exists during the call to the alias, so there is no collision concern. I personally use `f` in all of mine, short for function, to keep the visual focus on the function itself.  It's practically an anonymous function so your alias can do any shell code within the brackets as if you were calling a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

You can define aliases that are interpreted by the shell, by prefixing a `!` to the alias value. Your args will still be appended to the full command, but you can use trickery to avoid that and do your own thing instead. With my shell the following does the trick, though it's a little more magical than I'd like:

```
cof = !git checkout feature/$1; shift;
```

Comment: It still gives me the result: error: pathspec 'featuere-name' did not match any file(s) known to git. what do I do wrong?

Comment: P.S: This is when I type git cof feature-name

Comment: This is still not working. Can you help me some more?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to add a sjell script (even on Windows) called:

```
git-cof
```

(no extension)

In it, you can write any bash script you need:

```
#!/bin/bash
git checkout feature/$1
```

And you can call it as `git cof feature-name`.

Again this works even  on Windows, and any `git-xxx` script in the `$PATH/%PATH%` can be called with the command `git xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719966/git-alias-to-add-prefix-to-name-of-new-branch) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters), based on [Jan Krügers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296681/7598462) using shell scripts.

For your alias, the following is working for me:

```
cof = "!bt() { git checkout feature/$1;}; bt"
```

EDIT: You *do* just want to check out an existing branch, and not create a new one, do you? Else, you would have to add `-b`.

Comment: The `bt` here is a cpoy-paste relic and does not really make sense. It should be replaced with `cof` or something. It's just the name for the function defined in `{}`.