# Merge and delete branch in one step/command

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Is it possible, to `merge` a branch and automatically `delete` it with a single command? The delete step should only be executed if merging was successful.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

No, git doesn't support this at the same time.

However, you can run the commands in a shell conditionally:

```
git merge source-branch && git branch -d source-branch
```

**Edit:**

`-d` will only remove merged branches while `-D` will also remove unmerged branches, so `-d` will ensure that the branch is merged and you don't delete a branch by accident.

Comment: For me `-d` refuses to merge branches not merged in origin so I also need to do: `git push --delete origin source-branch` before I an apply this solution.

Comment: `git push origin --delete source-branch` to also delete on origin.

Answer (score 17):

This is an old question, but for those who stumble upon it looking for this functionality, you can now add a Git alias to accomplish this. For example, in `.gitconfig`:

```bash
# ...

[alias]
  mgd = "!git merge $1 && git branch -d $1; #"
```

Then, you could run `git mgd branch-name` to merge and delete a branch in one go. Note that the lowercase `-d` flag ensures that the branch will only be deleted if it has already been fully merged; thus, you don't have to worry about the first command not working correctly and then losing the branch.

The exclamation point at the beginning of the alias signifies that this is a bash command, and `$1` stores the argument that the user passed in (i.e. the name of the branch to merge/delete).

**NOTE**: Do not leave out the comment character (`#`) at the end of the alias! It will not work without it. ([Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39523506/4713952))

Comment: Wouldn't the expansion of "git mgd branch-name" result in `!git git mg branch-name && git br -d branch-name; #`

Comment: @A.Rick Actually, no, because the exclamation point signifies that the alias should be run as a bash command. Thus, only the command is run, without `git` prefixed.

Answer (score 3):

I will write a script.

```
git branch | grep -v master | xargs git merge &&
git branch | grep -v master | xargs git branch -d
```

Here the branch name `master` can be replaced by your current branch name.

Don't forget the `&&`. If the first line fails then the second is not executed.