# How to use 302 redirect to redirect a file upload request to s3 presigned url?

Tags: amazon-s3, api-design

I am working on a backend API to store articles and their metadata, the API is designed as the following way.

1. User should call `POST /api/articles` to create a file object with only its metadata at first, and get an object ID 123;
2. Then the user could call `POST /api/articles/123/file` to upload the file to backend.

A simple way to implement step 2 is to first upload file to my backend server, and then in the backend server I can upload the file to a s3 bucket. But this method is inefficent as the file has been uploaded 2 times (browser -> backend -> s3).

I learn that s3 is allowed to create presigned url for such use case, but I don't know how to use it with my design. One possbile solution is to response with a 302 redirect at Step 2 but I don't fine any cases to use it that way.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507239/merge-and-delete-branch-in-one-step-command