# How to add custom named arguments to git aliases

Tags: git, git-alias

Currently my git aliases all have to depend on the arguments being passed in a specific order, accessing them with `$1`, `$2`, etc.

What I would want to do is something like

`git sync --from="dev" --to="uat"`

Where `sync` is the alias where I would want to access the values of `$from` and `$to`

Is this possible in some way?

EDIT - This is not a question of how to use existing git commands with named parameters in aliases. I'm already using the `"sync = !sh -c '<bunch of commands here>'"` format to handle this. I want to create my own ***custom*** parameters for my aliases so I don't have to use `$1`, `$2`, `$3` in my script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git alias with positional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

As you've no doubt noticed, the `alias` functionality doesn't support named parameters.  The best you can do, then, is to write your "bunch of commands" into a script that also parses the command line.

So if we recast the quesiton as, how do I parse command line arguments in a shell script, you can find some help here: [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)