# how to make a git alias with arguments in windwos

Tags: git, alias

I have to use this command frequently

> git difftool head head~2 -- Myefile.cpp.

It is a large command to type all the time. I would like to make an alias of this command with `head~n` where `n` is a variable. I want to type

> git myfilediff n

where `n` is an integer number.

How can I do it in windows 10?

Comment: yes, tired few options. But I get error. I could make simple alias without no argument

Comment: You can read that : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39523506/2394026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution, to define a bash function in `~/.bashrc` if you are using Ubuntu or git-bash-for-windows:

```
function mfd() {
    git diff HEAD HEAD~${1} -- Myfile.cpp
}
```

`source ~/.bashrc` and then `mfd 2` is equivalent to `git diff HEAD HEAD~2 -- Myfile.cpp`.

Comment: Why is it a "dirty" solution ?

Comment: @Flows not robust, like a draft.

Comment: I am in windows 10. I made a file named .bashrc under c:\Users\ma. ma is my username. I put this function. Later tried in git bash. It does nothing. No error output. Also I put it inside .gitconfig. It throws error in git bash.

Comment: @masiboo Run `git-bash.exe` and edit `~/.bashrc`. After that, run `source ~/.bashrc` or re-open `git-bash.exe`