# Pushing up to commit with --set-upstream?

Tags: git, git-push

Let's take this case I'm having right now:

```
$ git log --decorate
commit A (HEAD -> dev)
commit B
commit C
commit D
commit E
commit F (origin/dev)
```

Now, if I want to push up to HEAD, since I've already done `--set-upstream`, I can just `git push`.

In my case, I want to push on `dev`, but only up to commit `C`, since I often amend/squash/rephrase the latest few commits I have. I can do `git push origin C:dev`, but isn't there a less verbose way of doing that, given that I've set the `dev` branch to track `origin/dev`? I.e., is there a way for me not to have to specify the remote and the branch, but still push up to a certain commit?

Comment: Hmmm... It would be possible using a [git alias with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters). But that sounds more like a workaround than a real solution that uses `push`.

Answer (score 1):

> I can do git `push origin C:dev`, but isn't there a less verbose way of doing that ...

Not exactly *less verbose*, but perhaps *easier*.<sup>1</sup>  I assume that for `C` you mean the hash ID of commit `C`.  There's also something else you can do.  Depending on how you like to work, you might find this better, or not.  See the section below the footnote.

When using the syntax `git push remote refspec` like this, with a *`refspec`* argument that contains a literal colon `:` character, the thing on the left side of the refspec argument can be *anything* that selects the desired commit.  A raw hash ID works well, but so does a relative name like `HEAD~2` or `dev~2`, and you can abbreviate the full hash ID to as short as four characters as long as this uniquely identifies the object.

The complete list of all possible ways to name any given commit are listed in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

---

<sup>1</sup>This depends on what you find easy, and how you count "verbose".  A raw hash ID is 40 characters and `dev~2` is 5, so obviously `dev~2` is *shorter*, but in a way it's *more* verbose: it has three words in it, `dev`, `~`, and `2`.  Counting can be tricky as well, when you have a few solid commits you wish to push along with a few dozen or hundred wobbly ones you want to avoid pushing yet—cut and paste of the raw hash ID may work better here.

---

#### A different, maybe better, workflow

The problem here arises because you're working on a branch you have named `dev`, which is kind of generic.  Suppose instead you had a branch named `wobbly-feature-xyz` or perhaps `wip/xyz`, where `wip` stands for *work in progress* and is a signal to everyone in your group that *this* branch is going to have its history rewritten regularly and commits within it should not be depended-upon.  Then you could safely save the in-progress, wobbly commits in the other Git at `origin` (which perhaps is more reliable and gets regular backups and so on), knowing that no one will depend on them the way they are likely to depend on commits in `dev`.

This lets you use `git rebase -i` to edit the history of your wobbly branch as much as you like.  When you have some commits *within* that wobbly branch that you feel are solid and should go into `dev`, you can put them there.

Let's say we start out with this repository in your Git and the Git at `origin` and, well, pretty much everyone else:

```
...--A--B--C   <-- master
         \
          D--E   <-- dev
              \
               G--H--I   <-- wip/xyz
```

You now work on your feature branch `wip/xyz` while others work on *their* `wip` feature branches.  Alice decides some commit(s) are done and ready to go and gets them into `dev` so after you run `git fetch origin`, your repository now has:

```
...--A--B--C   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          D--E   <-- dev
             |\
             | F   <-- origin/dev
             \
              G--H--I   <-- wip/xyz, origin/wip/xyz
```

You can now fast-forward your `dev` to pick up the new commit, more or less at any time:

```
...--A--B--C   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          D--E--F   <-- dev, origin/dev
              \
               G--H--I   <-- wip/xyz, origin/wip/xyz
```

and then, at any time as well, use `git rebase` to copy your three WIP commits:

```
      ...         G'-H'-I'  <-- wip/xyz
         \       /
          D--E--F   <-- dev, origin/dev
              \
               G--H--I   <-- origin/wip/xyz
```

and then force-push since everyone has agreed that this sort of thing happens:

```
     ...--D--E--F   <-- dev, origin/dev
                 \
                  G'-H'-I'  <-- wip/xyz, origin/wip/xyz
```

If you now feel that the *first* of your three commits is quite solid, you can now `git checkout` your own `dev` and fast-forward-merge that commit into it:

```
     ...--D--E--F   <-- origin/dev
                 \
                  G'  <-- dev
                   \
                    H'-I'  <-- wip/xyz, origin/wip/xyz
```

Now you can `git push` while on `dev` to push commit `G'`, giving:

```
     ...--D--E--F--G'  <-- dev, origin/dev
                    \
                     H'-I'  <-- wip/xyz, origin/wip/xyz
```

Except for the fact that you are now permitted (but not obligated) to push your work-in-progress commits, this has the exact same effect, as far as all *other* Git repositories go, as what you're doing now.  The key difference is that the *label* `dev` in *your* repository moves forward under your control at more specific times, so that you never have "wobbly" commits on your own `dev`.

(This may, or may not, make it easier for *you* to keep track of which commits you think are solid.)

Comment: The workflow you describe is good ; it's what I do at work. My specific question is on a personal project (i.e., not for work) that I'm the only one to work on. You could say that I'm experimenting git a little bit while working on my project. Maybe I should have mentioned that. As for the answer of my actual question, yeah, I had already figured I could do that (I love git's _commitish_ feature, like `HEAD~` or `HEAD^2`), but I still have to type the name of the branch I want to push on as well as the remote, so that doesn't make use of the `--set-upstream` feature.