# if-else on arguments in npm run script

Tags: npm, sh, package.json, csh

I would like to call different other scripts, depending on whether a paramter is given or not:

```
"paramtest": "if [ -z $1 ]; then echo Foo $1; else echo Bar; fi",
```

> npm run paramtest

should give "Bar".

> npm run paramtest -- whatever

should give "Foo whatever".

**However in practice I only get:** (The parameter is added to the whole line, not 'passed in')

```
> if [ -z $1 ]; then echo Foo; else echo Bar; fi "whatever
  sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected
```

**What can I do better?**

Essentially I am after running full test suite / only individual test with the same command...

```
"test" : "if [ -z $1 ]; then mocha ./test/**/*.test.js; else mocha $1
```

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: Not so far.....

Comment: [scripty](https://npmjs.com/package/scripty) is a handy module for moving npm scripts into dedicated files; I find it easier then cramming bash into JSON strings.
Bonus: using the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) will let you write your npm scripts in Node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping it in a shell function should do the trick:

```json
"test": "f() { if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then mocha './test/**/*.test.js'; else mocha -- \"$@\"; fi; }; f"
```

Note that I changed the if condition and the else branch slightly so you can specify multiple file arguments if necessary.

A more succinct method:

```json
"test": "f() { mocha -- \"${@:-./test/**/*.test.js}\"; }; f"
```

Using a shell function this way might look familiar, as the same technique is often used for [git aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters).

---

#### Detailed Explanation

Let's use this script for demonstration:

```json
"scripts": {
    "myscript": "if [ \"$1\" = one ]; then printf %s\\\\n \"$@\"; else echo false; fi"
}
```

Here if the first argument is "one", we print all the arguments, and otherwise we print "false". We are of course assuming that `npm run-script` is using an sh-like shell, and not, e.g., Windows' cmd.exe.

I can't see anything in the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) specifically detailing *how* arguments are passed to the script, so let's take a look at the source code (npm v6.14.7 at the time of writing). It seems that the script is joined with its arguments [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/v6.14.7/lib/run-script.js#L169) and is then executed  [here](https://github.com/npm/npm-lifecycle/blob/v3.1.5/index.js#L311). Essentially, `npm run myscript -- one two three` becomes

```sh
sh -c 'if [ "$1" = one ]; then printf %s\\n "$@"; else echo false; fi "one" "two" "three"'
```

Our arguments `one two three` are simply quote-escaped and concatenated to the script command. In terms of the shell grammar, this means that they are ending up as arguments to `fi`. `sh` of course rejects this because `fi` is just a builtin to end `if` and takes no arguments.

Our goal is something more like

```sh
sh -c 'if [ "$1" = one ]; then printf %s\\n "$@"; else echo false; fi' sh "one" "two" "three"
```

Here `one`, `two`, and `three` are arguments to sh itself and thus become the argument variables `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` in the given script. npm doesn't let us do this directly, but we can accomplish the same thing by wrapping our script in a shell function:

```json
"scripts": {
    "myscript": "f() { if [ \"$1\" = one ]; then printf %s\\\\n \"$@\"; else echo false; fi; }; f"
}
```

The script here ends with an invocation of the function, so npm will end up concatenating the arguments to this invocation, ultimately calling the function as `f "one" "two" "three"`:

```sh
sh -c 'f() { if [ "$1" = one ]; then printf %s\\n "$@"; else echo false; fi; }; f "one" "two" "three"'
```