# yarn/npm: Execute depending on set variable

Tags: bash, npm, yarnpkg

I basically [took this bash recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864829/444255) to run different commands based on whether a `package.json` script is called with or without a parameter...

```json
"scripts": {
    "paramtest": "if [ -z $1 ]; then echo \"var is unset\"; else echo \"var is set to {$1}\"; fi",
    ...
```

**Calling without a parameter works as expected:**

```bash
$>yarn paramtest
var is unset
$>npm run paramtest
var is unset
$>
```

**Calling with a parameter gives me an error:**

```bash
$>yarn run paramtest foo
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
$>npm run paramtest -- foo

> photocmd@0.0.7 paramtest /depot/own/photocmd

sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected
...
```

### What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835221/pass-command-line-argument-to-child-script-in-yarn#answer-50862023) answer and [this](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5207#issuecomment-356905873) comment, [`yarn run`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/) only supports passing arguments to the end of a script, and not to the middle. This behaviour is analogous to [`npm run`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script).

To circumvent this limitation you'll need to place your current conditional logic in the body of a [bash function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html). For instance:

```json
"scripts": {
  "paramtest": "func () { if [ -z \"$1\" ]; then echo \"var is unset\"; else echo \"var is set to ${1}\"; fi ;}; func",
...
```

Now when you pass an argument to the script via your CLI it gets:

1. Added to the end of the `paramtest` script, i.e. after the `func` invocation.
2. Subsequently passed as an argument to the `func` function itself.
3. In the body of the `func` function the first parameter is referenced using `$1` in the test, and `${1}` in the `echo` string.

Note: The `$1` in the test is wrapped in json escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"$1\"`

**Running the script:**

When passing an argument to your script via your CLI it would be safer to also include `--` between the script name, (i.e. `paramtest`), and the argument (`foo`). For instance:

```
yarn run paramtest -- foo
                   ^^
```

Because if your argument begins with a hyphen (as shown in the following command) it will be interpreted as an option:

```
yarn run paramtest -foo
                   ^
```

and your script will print:

> `var is unset`

However, adding the `--` as shown in the following example;

```
yarn run paramtest -- -foo
                   ^^ ^
```

correctly prints:

> `var is set to -foo`

Comment: The same solution is also applicable to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401352/if-else-on-arguments-in-npm-run-script).