# git how to mark commits to drop for generating a PR branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I want to generate a PR branch by removing my personal commits

is there ANY way to mark a list of commits to drop

I thought about :

1. ALWAYS start personal commits with `--p:` or anything unique
2. tag personal commits: but this would pollute my tag space: too many tags,
   also, you can't have 2 tags with the same name

   features I want: hidden tags, tags with same name

I could but idk where to feature request to git, to add a way to mark commits.

is there a better way to mark commits ? or generate a PR branch without my personal commits ?

Comment: What does remove a commit mean? Remove the message or remove what the commit did?

Comment: remove what the commit did, my solution would be to `git checkout -b PR_branch` , rebase and drop these commits

Comment: Yes, that's a good plan. So basically you're trying to script that somehow?

Comment: yes, preferably as a git alias

Answer (score 0):

so, I've decided to always start personal commits with `--p:` and made some git aliases:

but I can't predict the future: which changes won't be wanted?
I found a way to mark them AFTER.

## MARKING AFTER

#### If you have unwanted changes that **span many commits**, or are **inside useful commits**

1. remove your personal changes
2. commit
3. `git revertP`

#### `revertP`

reverts the last commit and starts the revert message with `--p:`

```sh
revertP = "!HEADID=$(git rev-parse HEAD) && git revert --no-commit HEAD && git commit -m \"--p: revert\" -m \"This reverts commit $HEADID.\" #"
```

the actual message is:

```sh
--p: revert

This reverts commit $HEADID.
```

#### if you want to mark a past commit

1. `git revertID <commit>`

#### `revertID`

self-explanatory (you really should understand the commands before running them)

```sh
revertID = "!git revert --no-edit $1 && git revertP #"
```

examples: `git revertID 0d299bd2`, `git revertID "HEAD^5"`

---

## DROPPING

#### `drop`

drop all commits starting with `--p:`: BEWARE, this works on your CURRENT branch

```sh
drop = "!GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=\"sed -i '/^pick .\\{7\\} --p:/  s/^pick/drop/'\" git rebase -i --root #"
```

(I guess rebasing from root is inefficient but faster than specifying the starting point)

#### `generate`

takes the 1st command line argument (name of the PR branch)

```sh
generate = "!CURRENT=$(git current) && git checkout -b $1 && git drop #"
```

example:
`git generate pr1` will checkout to new branch `pr1` and `git drop`

usually you'd use `git generate` and not `git drop`

---

here's what to put in .gitconfig, for me global config is at: `C:\Users\<user>\.gitconfig`

```sh
[alias]
    drop = "!GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=\"sed -i '/^pick .\\{7\\} --p:/  s/^pick/drop/'\" git rebase -i --root #"
    generate = "!CURRENT=$(git current) && git checkout -b $1 && git drop #"
    revertP = "!HEADID=$(git rev-parse HEAD) && git revert --no-commit HEAD && git commit -m \"--p: revert\" -m \"This reverts commit $HEADID.\" #"
    revertID = "!git revert --no-edit $1 && git revertP #"
```

---

thanks to [Git alias with positional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters#answer-39523506)