# Git alias script to treat all arguments as one string

Tags: git, git-config

Currently, I got following alias

```
[alias]
    comment = commit -m
```

It works fine for

```
git comment 'Export env'
```

But wanted to make it work without quotes

```
[alias]
    comment = !"git commit -m ${*}"
```

This runs into errors

```
$ git comment Export env
error: pathspec 'env' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'Export' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'env' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Comment: These error messages are what you'd get if you executed `git commit -m Export env Export env`.

Comment: @Cem That's exactly what the OP wants to fix. The question is how to write an alias so it accepts all arguments and combines it into a single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do things in complex ways when the answer for question ["How to write an alias that accepts parameters"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+alias+parameters) is quite [well-known](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322412/7976758) — use a shell function inside an alias:

```
git config alias.comment '!f() { git commit -m "$*"; }; f'
```

Examples (with `echo git commit "$*"`):

```
$ git comment test
git commit -m test

$ git comment foo bar
git commit -m foo bar
```

It's not obvious from the `echo` output it is exactly one parameter "foo bar" but it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could invoke a shell.  eg:

```
[alias]
        comment = !bash -c 'git commit -m \"$*\"' _
```

Comment: What's underscore is for?

Comment: The first argument passed to the script is expected to be the name of the shell  (eg, usually $0 is something like "sh" or "bash"), and using _ is a common convention for an argument that is effectively discarded.  If you omit `_`, then `$*` will not include the first argument.