# How to get display code that are modified code using git

Tags: git

I have project which is committed in locally, now I want to see the changes made in the project with the modified code, I want output like as follows :

```
  commit 54576760f3437ta3s457999d3ef606
  Author: Rajesh
  Date:   Tue Nov 13 1:40:55 2012 +0100

   class myFile {
      ....
      //modified code should getdisplayed
   }
```

What is the command can i use for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436362/shorthand-for-diff-of-git-commit-with-its-parent).

```
git show 54576760f3437ta3s457999d3ef606
```