# How can I see the changes in a Git commit?

Tags: git, version-control, diff, git-diff

When I do `git diff COMMIT` I see the changes between that commit and HEAD (as far as I know), but I would like to see the changes that were made by that single commit.

I haven't found any obvious options on `diff` / `log` that will give me that output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shorthand for diff of git commit with its parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436362/shorthand-for-diff-of-git-commit-with-its-parent)

Answer (score 2835, accepted):

To see the diff for a particular `COMMIT` hash, where `COMMIT` is the hash of the commit:

`git diff COMMIT~ COMMIT` will show you the difference between that `COMMIT`'s ancestor and the `COMMIT`. See the man pages for [git diff](http://jk.gs/git-diff.html) for details about the command and [gitrevisions](http://jk.gs/gitrevisions.html) about the `~` notation and its friends.

Alternatively, `git show COMMIT` will do something very similar. (The commit's data, including its diff - but not for merge commits.) See the [git show manpage](http://jk.gs/git-show.html).

(also `git diff COMMIT` will show you the difference between that `COMMIT` and the head.)

Comment: Note that the `^` needs to be quoted in the Thomson and Bourne shells (synonym for `|` there) and `rc` and its derivatives (caret operator) and in `zsh` with extendedglob enabled (`not` globbing operator)

Comment: This doesnt work anymore. git diff HEAD^ HEAD doesn't show anything.

Comment: @user3690202, yes it does. If the diff doesn't show anything, it means the diff is empty (there's no difference between `HEAD^` and `HEAD`). This can especially be the case when you do things like ignoring whitespace, or if you simply have to identical commits.

Comment: There was definitely a non-whitespace commit there - I know because I just committed it literally 5 minutes before trying to view what I committed. There must be some other situations where this doesn't work.

Comment: @user3690202, if that continues to be a problem (or just interests you), you should open a new question describing your situation in detail and trying to reproduce it ;)

Comment: Note that `HEAD^` implies first parent in case a commit has multiple parents (ie merge commit).

Comment: `git diff COMMIT~ COMMIT` works for me, notice the tilde instead of caret. I'm running git version 2.6.1.windows.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: "git show COMMIT" didn't work for me, but "git show $COMMIT" did.  I think this is a typo in the answer?

Comment: @tradetree: the word COMMIT is supposed to be replaced with the name of some commit, e.g. the SHA sum.

Comment: I feel like git show is more appropriate for this question and should be the suggestion mentioned first.

Comment: If using bash, `COMMIT^ COMMIT` can be abbreviated as `COMMIT{^,}`.

Comment: @JuusoOhtonen In theory a single `^` would do the same thing as a single `~`, but I believe you need to put quotes around the `^` as Stephane suggested.  That's what I found to be the case when running git from the Windows command prompt.

Comment: You can also extend this command with file specification (for example to exclude fixture files):
`git diff COMMITID^ COMMITID *.yml` 


<--- shows only changed yml files

Comment: This answer contains too much obscuring information (long introduction about `git diff` which already known by author)

Comment: There should be command `git diff COMMIT^` (literal). Nobody cares what the most recent commit hash is.

Comment: Note that there is no way to show only diff  by `git show`. If you want to output only diff, use `git diff`.

Comment: I'm trying to run these commands on a GitHub action that uses Ubuntu, and it doesn't like `git diff $GITHUB_SHA^ $GITHUB_SHA`. It gives the error: `fatal: ambiguous argument '<GITHUB_SHA>^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` I've also tried with the ~. Any ideas on how to get this to work in a Github action workflow?

Comment: *NB:* `git show` does not work for stash commits--frustratingly, it only shows the name of the commit but not the file changes.  `git diff COMMIT~ COMMIT` works for stash commits.

Answer (score 674):

As mentioned in "[Shorthand for diff of git commit with its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449128/6309)", you can also use [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) with:

```
git diff COMMIT^!
```

or

```
git diff-tree -p COMMIT
```

With git show, you would need (in order to focus on diff alone) to do:

```
git show --color --pretty=format:%b COMMIT
```

The `COMMIT` parameter is a **[commit-ish](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_commit-ish)**:

> A [commit object](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_commit_object) or an [object](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_object) that can be recursively dereferenced to a commit object. The following are all commit-ishes: a commit object, a [tag object](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_tag_object) that points to a commit object, a tag object that points to a tag object that points to a commit object, etc.

See [gitrevision "SPECIFYING REVISIONS"](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_revisions) to reference a commit-ish.
See also "[What does tree-ish mean in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18605496/6309)".

Answer (score 626):

You can also try this easy way:

```
git show <COMMIT>
```

Comment: It seems this does something quite different

Comment: It only shows the commit message. Not the diff of the code changes applied for this commit.

Comment: Sometimes, this command shows the commit message.

Comment: For me with git version 2.32.0, I see both the commit message as well as the file diffs/changes from the previous commit (just like the accepted answer does).  To be clear, `git show c411d33e` shows both commit message and file changes and `git diff c411d33e~ c411d33e` shows just the file changes.  In both cases changes file changes shown are from the commits ancestor.

Comment: yeah it will only show the log meta-data if it was a rebase or merge i think. use the commit hash in the message if it's there for useful analysis

Comment: @k0pernikus If you're **not getting the diff** it may be a merge commit. You need `git show <COMMIT> --diff-merges=on` in this case.

Answer (score 123):

`git show` shows the changes made in the most recent commit. It is equivalent to `git show HEAD`.

`git show HEAD~1` takes you back one commit.

Answer (score 73):

I usually do:

```
git diff HEAD~1
```

To show the changes regarding the last commit. If you have more commits just increase the number 1 to how many commits diff you want to see.

Comment: To show the changes of the last commit, simply use `git show` ;)

Comment: @xeruf that does only shows the commit message for me.

Answer (score 68):

Use:

```
git show <commit_sha>
```

This will show you just what's in that commit. You can do a range by just putting a space between the two commit SHA-1 hashes.

```
git show <beginning_sha> <ending_sha>
```

which is pretty helpful if you're rebasing often because your feature logs will all be in a row.

If you happen to want to look at the last 3 commits you can use the HEAD syntax

```
git show HEAD~3 HEAD
```

Comment: Is a SHA-1 hash the only possibility (not a rhetorical question)? What about, e.g., `HEAD~3`?

Comment: Yes, you could use something like `git show HEAD~3 HEAD` It's a little clunkier than other git commands, but it works.

Answer (score 50):

For me this works just fine

```
git show COMMIT --compact-summary
```

Which shows the next information

> Output a condensed summary of extended header information such as file creations or deletions ("new" or "gone", optionally "+l" if it’s a symlink) and mode changes ("+x" or "-x" for adding or removing executable bit respectively) in diffstat. The information is put between the filename part and the graph part. Implies --stat.

Comment: Upvoted because this was actually what I was looking for.  I stumbled onto this question because "see changes in commit" can mean a few different things.  I wanted to see the files that changed, not actually what changed in them.  Keep reading for very good answers to seeing _what changed in the file_.

Comment: Great answer. Like the output format of this command.

Comment: Here it says: fatal: unrecognized argument: --compact-summary

Comment: @AG_HIHI It sounds to me that  your git version does not have that option, you can check here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show 
Search the documentation for your specific git version if the option argument --compact-summary is available, if not, then upgrade to a newer one.

Answer (score 43):

First get the commit ID using,

```
git log #to list all
```

Or

```
git log -p -1 #last one commit id
```

Copy commit id.

Now we use two methods to list changes from a specific commit,

**Method 1:**

`git diff commit_id^!   #commit id something like this 1c6a6000asad012`

**Method 2:**

```
git show commit_id
For example: git show 1c6a600a
```

Comment: What does the `^!` mean??

Comment: ^! is the shorthand for commit^..commit which means will exclude all parents and check diff in that commit

Comment: I'm not an expert but I have a case (with multiple branches being involved) where git log c^! is not exactly the same as git log c^..c. In fact it's much better: git log c^..c listed too many entries while git log c^! did the right thing, so this is what I was looking for for a long time

Answer (score 31):

From the man page for [git-diff(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html):

```
git diff [options] [<commit>] [--] [<path>…]
git diff [options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>…]
git diff [options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…]
git diff [options] <blob> <blob>
git diff [options] [--no-index] [--] <path> <path>
```

Use the 3rd one in the middle:

```
git diff [options] <parent-commit> <commit>
```

Also from the same man page, at the bottom, in the [Examples section](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_examples):

```
$ git diff HEAD^ HEAD      <3>
```

> Compare the version before the last commit and the last commit.

Admittedly it's worded a little confusingly, it would be less confusing as

> Compare the most recent commit with the commit before it.

Comment: Your rewording would apply to `git diff HEAD HEAD^`.

Comment: git diff HEAD^ HEAD doesn't display any changes.

Comment: @user3690202 so that implies that there aren't any changes to display. Is that actually the case?

Comment: How can there not be any changes to display? If you want to view the last commit, surely unless it is a completely new repository there will be some changes to display?

Comment: @user3690202 it's possible to make an "empty commit" with Git that doesn't actually contain any changes from the parent, although there is a built-in safeguard that checks for and prevents this, though it is overridable with a command line option. I doubt that you would intentionally create an empty commit, so another possibility is that you somehow have pre-commit line-ending conversion on (or other funny whitespace stuff) that is tricking Git into thinking that no changes have actually been made. What platform are you running Git on?

Comment: @user3690202 use "": `git diff "HEAD^" HEAD`, worked for me

Answer (score 28):

The following seems to do the job; I use it to show what has been brought in by a merge.

```
git whatchanged -m -n 1 -p <SHA-1 hash of merge commit>
```

Comment: Would that work too with `git log`? (because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18585297/6309)

Comment: git log --name-only - for listing the changed files. Or git log --name-status --find-renames - to get the list of changed files with the kind of change (added/modified/renamed, etc)

Comment: Something I learned today. Thanks! 


**Official DESCRIPTION**
` Shows commit logs and diff output each commit introduces.`

       New users are encouraged to use git-log(1) instead. The whatchanged command is essentially the same as git-log(1) but defaults to show the raw format diff output and to skip merges.

       The command is kept primarily for historical reasons; fingers of many people who learned Git long before git log was invented by reading Linux kernel mailing list are trained to type it.`

Answer (score 24):

Another possibility:

```
git log -p COMMIT -1
```

Answer (score 17):

I like the below command to compare a specific commit and its last commit:

```
git diff <commit-hash>^-
```

Example:

```
git diff cd1b3f485^-
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use `git diff HEAD HEAD^1` to see the diff with the parent commit.

If you only want to see the list of files, add the `--stat` option.

Comment: This is what you mean, git diff HEAD^1 HEAD

Comment: Note that this will show what you added as removed, as it will do a reverse comparison. The way you should read the `diff` command is: what would I need to change in the file to get from commit `HEAD` to commit `HEAD^1`?

Answer (score 11):

```
git difftool COMMIT^ <commit hash>
```

is also possible if you have configured your difftool.

See here how to [configure difftool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412516/configuring-diff-tool-with-gitconfig). Or the manual page [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool.html).

Additionally, you can use `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <commit hash>` to see which files been changed/committed in a give commit hash.

Comment: IMO `git difftool -d` is more usable than plain `git difftool`.

Answer (score 10):

To see author and time by commit, use `git show COMMIT`. Which will result in something like this:

```
commit 13414df70354678b1b9304ebe4b6d204810f867e
Merge: a2a2894 3a1ba8f
Author: You <you@you.com>
Date:   Fri Jul 24 17:46:42 2015 -0700

     Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/your-feature'
```

If you want to see which files had been changed, run the following with the values from the *Merge* line above, `git diff --stat a2a2894 3a1ba8f`.

If you want to see the actual diff, run `git --stat a2a2894 3a1ba8f`.

Comment: "If you want to see the actual diff, run `git --stat a2a2894 3a1ba8f`". I think you mean `git diff a2a2894 3a1ba8f` or else `unknown option: --stat`.

Comment: `git show COMMIT` already shows the changeset for normal commits. It only won't show it for merges.

Answer (score 9):

**For checking complete changes:**

```
  git diff <commit_Id_1> <commit_Id_2>
```

**For checking only the changed/added/deleted files:**

```
  git diff <commit_Id_1> <commit_Id_2> --name-only
```

**NOTE**: For checking diff without commit in between, you don't need to put the commit ids.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to see the changes in the latest commit, simply `git show` will give you that.

Answer (score 8):

The following code will show the current commit

```
git show HEAD
```

Answer (score 7):

#### More minimalist approach for checking file changes (example)

```bash
# 1. Checkout a branch and see the list of commits
git log --oneline -5

# > Output
9b9b1f8 (HEAD -> master) Updated ABC
d58e5da chore: Added files
5a4aa2c chore: Added my pipeline
bb2b0b7 feat: Added ABC
473f711 feat: Added ZYX
```

```bash
# 2. Pick a commit hash and check which files were modified
git show --stat --oneline d58e5da

# > Output
d58e5da chore: Added versioning files
 Someabcfile                            | 18 ++++++++++++++++++
 myfolder/file.py                       | 19 +++++++++++++++++++
 myfolder/file.js                       |  7 +++++++
 myfolder/file.txt                      |  1 +
 4 files changed, 45 insertions(+)
```

```bash
# 3. Pick a file to check the differences
git show d58e5da myfolder12/file.py
```

Or, alternatively, check all file differences within a single commit from the list:

```bash
git show d58e5da
```

Answer (score 6):

A few answers miss a special case.
How to view changes made by the ***Root Commit*** as it does not have a parent/ancestor.

Both

`git diff <root_commit>^..<root_commit>`

and

`git diff <root_commit>~..<root_commit>`

throw an error.

```
$git diff 27e521ca73a46b2d3a28568dc49fced81e46aaea~ 27e521ca73a46b2d3a28568dc49fced81e46aaea
fatal: ambiguous argument '27e521ca73a46b2d3a28568dc49fced81e46aaea~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

`git diff <root_commit>^!`

shows diff btw **root commit** and HEAD. Like so:

```
$ git diff 27e521ca73a46b2d3a28568dc49fced81e46aaea^!
diff --git a/file1.txt b/file1.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..80f3f1a
--- /dev/null
+++ b/file1.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+Create the first file.
+
+Add some placeholder text to first file.
+
+
diff --git a/file2.txt b/file2.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..66e494f
--- /dev/null
+++ b/file2.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
+This is the second file.
+
+It has an uncommited commit.
+
+We use it to demo default `git diff` behaviour.
+
```

(These are changes made by all commits btw my **root commit** and HEAD).

For **Root Commit**

I find only

`git show --color --pretty=format:%b <root_commit_hash>`

works.

Like so:

```
$ git show --color --pretty=format:%b 27e521ca73a46b2d3a28568dc49fced81e46aaea

diff --git a/README b/README
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..12a04f0
--- /dev/null
+++ b/README
@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
+# git-diff-demo
+
+This repo documents the demo of the git diff command.
+We will have options, and use cases.
```

(My **root commit** added only the README)

Comment: hi, what is `root commit`?

Answer (score 6):

Get list of files changed in a commit:

`git show --name-only commit_id`

**Note**: Above command will not work for merge ids.

---

To get list of files changed in a merge commit id:

`git log -m -1 --name-only commit_id`

---

View changes in a **specific file** within a commit:
`git show commit_id:src/path/to/that/file`

Comment: it's better to use `git show commit_id -- src/path/to/that/file` to get color in output.

Answer (score 4):

This command will get you the Git parent commit-hash:

```
git log -n 2 <commit-hash>
```

After that `git diff-tool <commit-hash> <parent-commit-hash>`

Example:

```
bonnie@bonnie ~/ $ git log -n 2 7f65b9a9d3820525766fcba285b3c678e889fe3

commit 7f65b9a9d3820525766fcba285b3c678e889fe3b
Author: souparno <souparno.majumder@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 25 13:17:07 2016 +0530

CSS changed to maintain the aspect ratio of the channel logos and to fit them properly.

commit c3a61f17e14e2b80cf64b172a45f1b4826ee291f
Author: souparno <souparno.majumder@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 25 11:28:09 2016 +0530

The ratio of the height to width of the channel images are maintained.
```

After this

```
git difftool 7f65b9a9d3820525766fcba285b3c678e889fe3b c3a61f17e14e2b80cf64b172a45f1b4826ee291f
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm running Git version 2.6.1.windows.1 on Windows 10, so I needed a slight modification to Nevik's answer (tilde instead of caret):

```
git diff COMMIT~ COMMIT
```

Another option is to quote the caret:

```
git diff "COMMIT^" COMMIT
```

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to review changes between two commits for a specific file.

```
git diff <commit_Id_1> <commit_Id_2> some_dir/file.txt
```

Comment: `git diff <commit_Id> on/specific/file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

In case of checking the source change [in a graphical view](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk), use:

```
gitk (your commit id goes here)
```

For example:

```
gitk HEAD~1
```

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted. I agree that command line and text based stuff is the way to go but gitk gives a lot of useful information.

Comment: `gitk` is not `git` it's spécifique package and it doesn't exist on every OS where `git` could be installed.`tig` is also good tools as many others.

Answer (score -5):

1. You can click on each commit on the specific address of git to view
2. If you submit with a tool, you can pass show history

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32778316)