# Compare file to another file in another commit

Tags: git

I have moved some code from a file to another file, and applied little changes in it. I would like to have a diff to see those changes.

The problem seems pretty common to me, but I have never needed to do such a thing. I only know how to compare the same file with himself in a previous revision, or 2 different files in the same revision.

Are there `git diff` options to compare one file in the current revision to another file in another commit? Or any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563726/git-diff-for-one-commit

Comment: @kravasb I don't think it is a duplicate, I don't want to compare the whole commit to another commit, I just want the difference for that piece of code, so the new file compared to the other would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. HEAD~3 can be replaced with the commit id.

```
git diff HEAD~3:oldfile.xml file/in/another/path/newfile.xml
```

Comment: Learned a new thing today. :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### A dirty but working solution

Use [`git ls-tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) to get the SHA1 identifier of the files on the commits you want to compare then use [`git diff [options] <blob> <blob>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) and provide the two SHA1 identifiers as arguments.

```
$ git ls-tree commit1 dir1/dir2/file1.txt
100644 blob 7d252b754d46a8fcd0613a96710c9326942d7a92   dir1/dir2/file1.txt

$ git ls-tree commit2 dirA/fileB.txt
100644 blob 4d000ed739c880a26686a2843dae6eeeb4109a37   dirA/fileB.txt

$ git diff 7d252b754d46a8fcd0613a96710c9326942d7a92 4d000ed739c880a26686a2843dae6eeeb4109a37
```

If you need to do this frequently you can even pack everything in a small shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script does not validate its command line arguments!

COMMIT1=$1
FILE1=$2
COMMIT2=$3
FILE2=$4

BLOB1=$(git ls-tree $COMMIT1 $FILE1 | cut -f3 -d' ' | cut -f1)
BLOB2=$(git ls-tree $COMMIT2 $FILE2 | cut -f3 -d' ' | cut -f1)

git diff $BLOB1 $BLOB2
```

Run it as:

```
$ script.sh commit1 dir1/dir2/file1.txt commit2 dirA/fileB.txt
```

Comment: indeed @crea1 's solution looks like the way to go, thank you for the effort anyway!