# how to display changed code in a PR in UI before git push

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-diff, git-difftool

I am using VScode and git together and I am wondering whether there is a way or plugin to display the changes in UI in this PR before I `git push`. The current vscode diff tool does not display changes after `git commit`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see the changes in a Git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563726/how-to-see-the-changes-in-a-git-commit)

Comment: git show <COMMIT> should do it

Comment: you can diff two commits `git diff HEAD HEAD~1` or any other way of specifying a commit, or use the git graph, click on HEAD and then on the files of the commit