# How to diff a commit with its parent in GitPython

Tags: git-diff, gitpython

I'm working on a tool to find commits that only contain whitespaces changes using GitPython. In order to do so I need to see what a commit has changed from its parent.

The second answer to the question  [How to diff a commit with its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436362/how-to-diff-a-commit-with-its-parent) shows that I can see the differences between a commit and its parent using:

```
git diff 15dc8^!
```

What is the equivalent in gitpython?

I would be also happy to get the same information as with

```
git show $COMMIT
```

I'm new, I really hope my question follows all the community guidelines!

Comment: In the end I fixed my issue by using `res = repo.git.show(sha)`

Comment: You should post it as an answer an accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using

```
res = repo.git.show(sha)
```